# XQuery: create nested xml from sequence from jQuery AJAX post

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, nested, xquery

I'm using jQuery to serializeArray on some forms on a webpage.  That data is getting posted back to an XQuery page.  When I do:

```
xdmp:get-request-field('data')
```

I get a sequence of things like

```
data[0][name]
data[0][value]
data[1][name]
data[1][value]
```

etc

These should have values in them that look like:

```
data[0][name] = person.name.first
data[0][value] = Fred
data[1][name] = person.name.last
data[1][value] = Jones
data[2][name] = person.books-read.book[0].name
data[2][value] = Moby Dick
data[3][name] = person.books-read.book[0].page-count
data[3][value = 522
data[4][name] = person.books-read.book[0].name
data[4][value] = Bleak House
data[5][name] = person.books-read.book[0].page-count
data[5][value = 757
```

etc

For the life of me, I cannot figure out a dynamic way to loop through all these name/value pairs and turn them into a usable xml structure.

Ideally, I'd love something that looks like this:

```
<person>
    <name>
        <first>Fred</first>
        <last>Jones</last>
    </name>
    <books-read>
        <book>
            <name>Moby Dick</name>
            <page-count>522</page-count>
        </book>
        <book>
            <name>Bleak House</name>
            <page-count>757</page-count>
        </book>
    </books-read>
</person>
```

Suggestions?  Thoughts?  Anything to get started?!

Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLWOR

Answer (score 0):

You can use map-like structures to update existing XML, but that approach isn't well suited for adding elements that don't already exist in a given document, or for creating new documents.

It looks like those request parameters were generated from JSON. Since you are using MarkLogic (note `xdmp:get-request-field()` in your question), you can send the JSON instead of the serialized form, and use MarkLogic libraries to generate XML:

```
xquery version "1.0";
import module namespace json = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json" at "/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy";
declare namespace jsonb = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic";

declare variable $input :=
'{ "person": { "name": { "first": "Fred",
                         "last": "Jones" },
               "books-read": [
                 { "book": { "name": "Moby Dick",
                             "page-count": 522 } },
                 { "book": { "name": "Bleak House",
                             "page-count": 757 } }] } }';

declare function local:walk-tree($x)
{
  for $y in $x/node()
  return local:transform($y)
};

declare function local:transform($x)
{
  typeswitch($x)
    case element(jsonb:json) return
      local:walk-tree($x)
    case element() return
      element { fn:local-name($x) } {
        $x/@* except $x/@type,
        local:walk-tree($x)
      }
    default return $x
};

local:transform( json:transform-from-json($input) )
```

The typeswitch transformation strips out the elements and attributes used by the MarkLogic JSON library to specify objects types.